# Como criar Número em fração para etiquetas VOLUMES

Tags: c#, c, mongodb-csharp

Estou criando um software que realiza a impressão de etiquetas para caixas (VOLUMES), no caso eu quero por. ORIGEM, DESTINO, QUANTIDADE DE VOLUMES, NÚMERO DA NOTA FISCAL. isso para me ajudar na hora do transporte, porém não consigo o seguinte:
-> Como é para volume, quero por um *TEXT BOX* para quantidade de volume exemplo: 100 caixas, e quero que ele automaticamente me dê: 1/100, 2/100, 3/100,5/100 e assim por diante, até chegar em 100/100. Vocês consegue me dar essa força?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Creio ... Um bom e velho WHILE  .... https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/

Answer (score -4):

coloque essa impressão dentro de um loop que vai incrementando :

```
int total = 100;
for(int i=1; i<=total; i++)
    printf("%d / %d", i, total );
```